# I have a set of 5 vectors and I want to subtract each vector from every other vector in Octave

Tags: for-loop, vector, octave

So, I want to be able to subtract A-B, A-C, A-D... for all possible combinations. Ideally this could be expanded to a larger set of vectors so the differences could be calculated quickly. I have been trying to figure out a for loop that might work.

I have very limited experience with octave, and I barely know how to code. I was encouraged to try writing a for loop but don't quite understand the dynamics.

Comment: Is it a homework?

Answer (score 1):

In Octave you don't have the choice apart putting the vectors in a 2D array that can be indexed. Then the results can be stored in a 3D array:

```m
X = [A(:) , B(:) , C(:) , D(:) , E(:)];
Y = zeros(size(X,1),size(X,2),size(X,2));
for j = 1:size(X,2)
    for k = 1:size(X,2)
        Y(:,k,j) = X(:,k) - X(:,j);
    end
end
```

`Y(:,i,j)` is the subtraction result of the j-th vector from the i-th vector

Note that a vector can be refered as `A(:)` or simply `A`, but there is a subtle difference here: Octave/Matlab makes a difference between column vectors and row vectors, depending on how they have been defined/assigned/created. So depending on the context `A` can be either column or row. In contrast, `A(:)` is always a column vector (which is put in the 1st column of the matrix `X` in the code above).

Comment: If you permute `X` to sizes [5,1,n] and to sizes [1,5,n] (with n being the length of `A`), then you can directly subtract those two, and skip the loops.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I assume you are relying on some broadcasting? It is maybe more efficient in some cases, but except in very simple cases I find the code difficult to read afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is the `nchoosek` function to generate 'pairs' of indices, and then using those indices to index an array (or cell array) of vectors to obtain their differences. E.g.

```
Vectors    = [10, 20, 30, 40; 20, 30, 40, 50; 30, 40, 50, 60; 40, 50, 60, 70];
IndexPairs = nchoosek( 1:4, 2 ).';
Diffs      = zeros( size( Vectors, 1), size( IndexPairs, 2 ) );

for i = 1 : size( IndexPairs, 2 )
    Diffs(:, i) = Vectors(:, IndexPairs(1, i)) - Vectors(:, IndexPairs(2, i))
endfor
```

<sub>Note: This only gives you differences in one direction. If you want the B-A etc ones two, simply duplicate the result with a negative sign.</sub>